# vim-bufexplorer click file on list move next

Tags: vim

I am using `vim-bufexplorer` on Mac.

When I click `\be` to show opened file list, and want to click a file from list, the cursor moved next line but not open that file.

Why?

---

## Addition

When I run `:verbose map \be`, it shown:

```
s  \           * b<BS>\                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        Last set from ~/.vim/bundle/snipMate/after/plugin/snipMate.vim                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
n  \be         & :BufExplorer<CR>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        Last set from ~/.vim/bundle/bufexplorer/plugin/bufexplorer.vim
```

Comment: you can debug maps using this something like this `:verbose map \be`. you should then see if the mapping exists and is wrongly mapped or if its just not mapped.

Comment: @Lynch Thank you. I have wrote my result. See above, please.

Comment: some where in the code it say this: ` <enter> or o or Mouse-Double-Click : open buffer under cursor`. are you sure you have double clicked and enabled mouse events in vim? (`:set mouse=a` to enable mouse events)

Comment: @Lynch Yes, I have put `set mouse=a` in my `~/.vimrc` file. And I also tried `o` or `Mouse-Double-Click`, the result was the same.

Comment: its supposed to be mapped to `:SelectBuffer()` according to code: https://github.com/jlanzarotta/bufexplorer/blob/master/plugin/bufexplorer.vim#L446 . I dont personnaly use this plugin. im affraid I cant help further more.

Comment: @Lynch Thank you very much. Maybe something is wrong about my Mac OS setting. It doesn't matter. Thank you all the same.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to the vim version.

I installed a new vim by brew and that becomes 7.4. But the system version is 7.3.

The point is how to change the vim version to the new one.

## Official issue

> https://github.com/jlanzarotta/bufexplorer/issues/37